# Iterating in DataFrame and writing down the index of the values where a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, dataframe

I have a data made of 20 rows and 2500 columns.
Each column is a unique product and rows are time series, results of measurements. Therefore each product is measured 20 times and there are 2500 products.

My data is defined as `DataFrame` and I want to write down the number of the row (index) where a specific condition (such as: `x> 3`) is met for the first time, for all columns(products, so that I will have an array in the end.

I tried using loops and iterrow but failed at executing.

P.S: I used `idxmax()` in order to get the row id of max value but this time I want to get the index of the cell where a condition is met for the first time and then break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.gt` + `.idxmax`, which will give you the index of the first time your condition is met.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,(20,2500)))

df.gt(3).idxmax()
#0        0
#1        0
#2        4
#3        4
#4        1
#...
#2496     8
#2497     0
#2498     5
#2499     1
```